# HttpWebRequest skipping specific drop down menu in web page

Tags: c#, asp.net, httpwebrequest, web-scraping

I am currently trying to scrape a website, and it is giving me a small amount of trouble. The webscraper is skipping a specific drop down menu in the web page.

The webpages are generated with asp.net. I can load the first page with a url, I then need to use a cookie with the url to load the other pages. The pages are then saved as .html files. The second url I load is missing data.

Once I have the .html files I parse them with HTMLAgilityPack.

This is the code that scrapes the site.

```
    static void saveWebPage(int ID) 
    {
        //The first page can be loaded via the url.
        //The rest  need an url and a cookie to be loaded.

        //1st page
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(webPage + ID.ToString());
        request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2.3) Gecko/20100401 Firefox/3.6.3";
        request.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";      
        CookieContainer aCookie = new CookieContainer();
        request.CookieContainer = aCookie;

        WebResponse pageResponse = request.GetResponse();

        Stream responseStream = pageResponse.GetResponseStream();
        TextWriter textDoc = new StreamWriter(ID.ToString() + "Page1.html");
        string html = string.Empty;

        using (StreamReader streamRead = new StreamReader(responseStream))
        {
            html = streamRead.ReadToEnd();
        }

        textDoc.Write(html);
        textDoc.Close();


        //2nd page
        HttpWebRequest request2 = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(webPage2 + ID.ToString());
        request2.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2.3) Gecko/20100401 Firefox/3.6.3";
        request2.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";  
        request2.CookieContainer = request.CookieContainer;

        pageResponse = request2.GetResponse();

        responseStream = pageResponse.GetResponseStream();
        textDoc = new StreamWriter(ID.ToString() + "Page2.html");
        html = string.Empty;

        using (StreamReader streamRead = new StreamReader(responseStream))
        {
            html = streamRead.ReadToEnd();
        }


        textDoc.Write(html);
        textDoc.Close();

        //........ More code in the same style.

        }
```

The webpage has several drop down menus. I can get data for all of them except for one specific one. HTML code for a menu I can grab might look like this:

```
    <td ><select name="menuName" id="menuID" disabled="disabled" style="menuStyle">
    <option selected="selected" value="-1">Title</option>
    <option value="1">A</option>
    <option value="2">B</option>
    <option value="3">C</option>
    <option value="4">D</option>
            //....... More options.
```

And I can parse that data. The problem menu looks like this on the site:

```
    <td ><select name="menuName" onchange="javascript:setTimeout(&#39;__doPostBack(\&#39;menuName\&#39;,\&#39;\&#39;)&#39;, 0)" id=*menuID disabled="disabled" style="width:menuWidth; position:static">
    <option value="-1">Title</option>
    <option value="1">A</option>
    <option selected="selected" value="2">B</option>
    <option value="3">C</option>
            //..... More options.
```

The .html file that my scraper creates looks like this:

```
    <td ><select name="menuName" onchange="javascript:setTimeout(&#39;__doPostBack(\&#39;menuName\&#39;,\&#39;\&#39;)&#39;, 0)" id="menuID" disabled="disabled" style="width:menuWidth; position:static">
    <option selected="selected" value="-1">Title</option>
```

I've already tried the scraper with and without the user agent option, but it didn't make any difference. I've also checked the website and I can grab other menus that run javascript:setTimeout on change. So is there any reason that my scraper is skipping the menu data and making the menu title as the selected value?

Edit:

Reloading the page with Fiddler brings up six results.

Request Headers all look like this:

CONNECT site.site.site:443 HTTP/1.1

Client User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/31.0.1650.63 Safari/537.36

Transport:

Connection: keep-alive

Host: site.site.site

Edit 2: Information from the raw view of the response in Fiddler.

```
<td ><select name="menuName" onchange="javascript:setTimeout(&#39;__doPostBack(\&#39;menuName\&#39;,\&#39;\&#39;)&#39;, 0)" id="menuID" disabled="disabled" style="width:menuWidth; position:static">
<option value="-1">Title</option>
<option value="1">A</option>
<option selected="selected" value="2">B</option>
<option value="3">C</option>
        //..... More options.
```

The header looked slightly different than what I am sending in my scraper, and the website is https, not http.

GET  https://site.site.site/**asp.x?page2 HTTP/1.1

Host: site.site.site

Connection: keep-alive

Cache-Control: max-age=0

Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8

User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) 
Chrome/32.0.1700.76 Safari/537.36

Referer: https://site.site.site/*asp.x?page1

Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch

Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8

Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=***SessionID

Comment: Please use Fiddler (or any other Http debugger) to see what actually reported by the site in each case. It is unclear where "The problem menu looks like this on the site:" information comes from - possibly from completely rendered page.

Comment: I'll look at it in Fiddler. The problem menu comes from viewing the source of the website in chrome.

Comment: I added data on the Headers tab from Fiddler to the the main body. What exactly am I looking for? I don't have much experience with Fiddler.

Comment: Look in Raw view of response - you are looking for how HTML that server returns look like (and what `HttpWebRequest` will be able to get) vs. what browser thinks it looks like.

Comment: OK, thanks. I looked at the menu in the raw view of the HTML code. It looked exactly like the html code in chrome. The request header looked slightly different though.

Comment: +1. I can't see why it happen by looking at it (also indeed HTML look very strange - looks like server side code is broken due to `*menuXXXX` values instead of something like `"menuXXXX"`). Consider to create small sample with just this small string and HtmlAgility pack to debug. I don't believe there is anything wrong with your `HttpWebRequest` code itself.

Comment: That is my fault, it has a long menu name so I removed it to make it more readable. It actually looks like this: "ct....ID" . So it uses "".

Comment: In any case, I think you need HtmlAgilityPack-only sample - consider asking new question with correct sample.